# What is this certain block of code doing within my function?

Tags: c++, function, max, frequency

This is the code as a whole. It takes an integer x and returns the most common digit within the integer x, also in the case of a tie it returns the greater value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int max_frequency(int x)
{
   int a[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
   int temp, max;
   while(x > 0)
   {
       temp = x%10;
       x=x/10;
       a[temp]++;
   }
   max = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
   {
       if(a[i] >= a[max])
       {
           max = i;
       }
   }
   return max;
}
int main()
{
   int x;
   cout << "Enter the integer: "<< endl;
   cin >> x;
   cout << max_frequency(x) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The part I am confused about:

```
int max_frequency(int x)
{
   int a[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
   int temp, max;
   while(x > 0)
   {
       temp = x%10;
       x=x/10;
       a[temp]++;
   }
   max = 0;
```

I understand that the array of 0's serves as a counter, what i don't understand is what's being assigned to the variable temp, and why. I had some help writing this code but it wasn't clearly explained to me what was going on here. If someone wouldn't mind explaining this piece, i'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Get a pen and some paper, and pretend you're a computer, and run this function by hand, and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that, what i come up with is for example, if the entered integer was 122, my temp would then be assigned a value of 12.2?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to assign "12.2" to an ***int***eger?

Comment: 122/10 is 12. You cannot store a decimal part in an int, it is silently discarded. (Actually it's discarded before you try to store it, because the compiler sees you're dividing two ints and infers the result should also be an int)

Comment: @immibis Wait actually, my temp would be assigned a value of 2, then it would increment. I thought this array was supposed to take the integer and enter digits into it as long as its less than a 10 digit integer

Comment: 122/10 is 12.2 though unless I am mistaken, the remainder would be 2?

Comment: I apologize if this was a poor question that doesn't follow the guidelines of this forum.

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux That is correct, 122%10 is 2, and 122/10 is 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` is the modulo operator, meaning `x%y` equals to the remainder of the division of x by y. In that case, we can see that `x%10` returns the right-most digit of x, right? Now we can count the digits of a number